# How do I use bootstrap's Darkly theme without external references?

Tags: url, css, bootstrap

I have used the bootstrap Darkly theme found [here](https://bootswatch.com/darkly/) in the past, and it has worked great. This time, I'm developing a website that will be displayed to users when they connect to a wireless network. Users connecting to this network will NOT have internet. This is giving me problems.

Darkly's bootstrap.min.css file has embedded references to fonts, and possibly other resources that are online. Browsers are expected to connect to external websites to get those.

Ex:

```
$ cat bootstrap.min.css | grep -o 'http[^ ]*\|https[^ ]*'

https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic");/*!
http://bootswatch.com
http://getbootstrap.com)
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/src/css/main.css
```

Is there any way to have these resources locally hosted on the same webserver that will be running my website? It doesn't appear that Darkly has a download with non-embedded resource URLs like vanilla bootstrap does.

The fonts URL seems to be the main one, but the resource it points to seems to be different depending on what browser or device you use to access it, so I'm not sure what to do about that.

Update: It appears the theme is hosted [here on github](https://github.com/thomaspark/bootswatch/), and has a fonts folder, but how would I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to grab each external resource and save it to a local file.  That may or may not be possible with all of them.

It certainly is for the CSS files, licenses etc but if it is pulling in something from `http://bootswatch.com` generally and not loading a file I am not sure what is happening.

Once you have save the files locally, depending on your programming language, you include that file in your script.  PHP looks like `include("/path/to/file.css");`

Comment: https://fonts.googleapis.com... was pointing to a file that basically listed the fonts the browser could download, along with URLs for each font. I changed the URL in my bootstrap.min.css to read `/static/fonts/list` instead. I then downloaded the file at that link, saved it as `list`, and changed all the URLs in it to point to local font files, which I also downloaded. Now when I visit the page and use firefox's Developer Network tool, I see that the only connections being made are to my server. Thanks